# SSRS combine tables with 3 key links

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

currently i have 2 datasets.
dataset 1 like this.

```
|batchno|brcode|inwardtype|txntype|processeddate|amount| 
|xxxxxxx|xxxxxx|xxxxxxxxxx|xxxxxxx|xxxxxxxxxxxxx|xxxxxx|
```

dataset 2 like this.

```
|batchno|brcode|inwardtype|txntype|processeddate|amount|glaccno|
|xxxxxxx|xxxxxx|xxxxxxxxxx|xxxxxxx|xxxxxxxxxxxx|xxxxxxx|xxxxxxx|
```

I need check the 3 link key "brcode", "batchno", "processeddate". then display the result like this.

```
|batchno|glaccount|brcode|amount|txntype|processeedate|
|xxxxxxx|xxxxxxxxx|xxxxxx|xxxxxx|xxxxxxx|xxxxxxxxxxxxx|
```

i have try to use the lookup to combine 2 tables. but it doesn't show any value in "glaccno" column. Seems like lookup max allow me put 2 source expression. I also try to join the tables. I used inner join, same problem. conditions is too much. sql only allow one condition by using inner join. Anyone can teach me how to solve this problem? thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a 1:1 relationship this expression should work even with 3 fields, because you just combine the fields with the `&`:

```
'Returns Fields!glaccno.Value from Dataset2

=Lookup(Fields!brcode.Value & Fields!batchno.Value & Fields!processeddate.Value, 
        Fields!brcode.Value & Fields!batchno.Value & Fields!processeddate.Value, 
        Fields!glacnco.Value, "DataSet2")
```

If you have a 1:n relationshipt you have to use `LookupSet()` instead of `Lookup()`.

Comment: error: Operator '&' is not defined for string "13112018" and type 'FieldImpl'.

Comment: I think i should try lookupset()

Comment: `Lookup()` should work for both cases 1:1 and 1:n. In 1:1 it returns the exact match in 1:n it returns the first match it finds. Based on your error description wrap a `CStr()` around the fields: `=Lookup(CStr(Fields!brcode.Value) & CStr(Fields!batchno.Value) & CStr(Fields!processeddate.Value), CStr(Fields!brcode.Value) & CStr(Fields!batchno.Value) & CStr(Fields!processeddate.Value), Fields!glacnco.Value, "DataSet2")`